# How to have lightbox on page load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Is there a way to have lightbox on page load??
Say like when the page is loading i need to show the lightbox... and when the page load is complete it should disappear??
Pls help me in this...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an absolute positioned div (in CSS) to show the lightbox and:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('idofthediv').style.display='none'" ...
```